# internal cross service communication - subscription or other?

Tags: graphql, graphql-subscriptions

I have an architecture question and would love to hear from your experience.
in a micro service environment. when 2 graphql API micro services that need to communicate with each other async via some kind of pub-sub mechanism. would you choose a graphql subscriptions? or something like kafka/rabitmq/etc type system.
are there any architectural rules I should follow? any criteria for this kind of decision?
thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphQL isn't necessarily a *bad* choice for inter-service communication, but it's not what GraphQL is designed and optimized for. For pub-sub in particular, Kafka and RabbitMQ are both popular choices. GraphQL subscriptions can theoretically be implemented over a queue such as Kafka, but this will add some complexity vs just using Kafka. The GraphQL spec doesn't speak much to how subscriptions should be implemented, and open source support is much less complete than for queries and mutations.

**Pros of subscriptions for service-service pub-sub:**

- GraphQL gives you a tool to specify the shape of messages (This could
  also be accomplished with schemas like Avro or Protobufs).
- GraphQL subscriptions allow subscribers to customize the payload that 
  they receive

**Cons:**

- It adds complexity to your system vs using Kafka client directly
- You will require more engineering cycles

**Some questions to consider:**

- How much time do you want to spend creating your own solution vs using off-the-shelf code?
- What aspects of GraphQL would you benefit from?

Comment: thanks for the ellaborate reply. specifically I'm using graphql-java library which has subsciption implementation built in. in this case, my java application code will have to act as a client and push messages both in the graphql-java sub implementation or to a kafka cluster, so in this regard kafka would make even less sense because it introduces a new component that I need to learn and take care of. I am just not sure if, like you mentioned, subsciptions in graphql were designed for inter process comms but rather designed for browser client use. hope I'm clearer now. still a bit baffled :)

Comment: It is possible to do the subscriptions with just the graphql-java node if you can run from a single server instance, but if you need a multi-node setup you'll usually have some sort of distributed pub-sub system behind it. If you do have success with the graphql subscription approach, I'd love to hear how it went!